# Microsoft bot service work perfectly fine in local but not in webchat channel

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

In local bot work perfectly fine but on web chat channel 'There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Gateway Timeout' error occurred but bot run correctly after 2nd respond

Controller code

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
        }
         else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
            IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = message as IConversationUpdateActivity;
            if (iConversationUpdated != null)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
                foreach (var member in iConversationUpdated.MembersAdded ?? System.Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
                {
                    // if the bot is added, then   
                    if (member.Id == iConversationUpdated.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        var reply = ((Activity)iConversationUpdated).CreateReply("Hi, Welcome to Systenics.");
                        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new EchoDialog());
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
           await HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Chat dialog

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.ShowOptions);
    }
    public virtual async Task ShowOptions(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {
        var message = await activity;
        var descriptions = new string[] { "Request a Quote", "More Information About Jobs" };
        PromptDialog.Choice(
            context: context,
            resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
            options: descriptions,
            prompt: "Please select an option below:",
            retry: "Selected option not available.",
            promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
            );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked logs? please share logs which will help to resolve this.

Comment: [12:52:53] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[12:52:53] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Hi, Welcome to Systenics. 
[12:52:54] <- POST 200 Reply[message] application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero 
[12:52:54] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[12:52:56] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Click on this link to know more about Jobs https:/... 
[12:52:56] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Thank You. 
[12:52:57] -> POST 200 [message] More Information About Jobs

Comment: Is this log from local or form azure?

Comment: yes log from local

Comment: You need to check logs from azure, as it already works in local.

Comment: i am not able to find log on azure where is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486516/6848279 this could help. You can also try enable diagnostic logs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you’d like to catch the `ConversationUpdate` activity and create&send a fake message to initialize the dialog in order to prompt for one of a set of choices via `PromptDialog.Choice()` method. I suggest that you can specify `Text` property of activity before you send it to initialize the dialog, and then you can do different operations by checking the message activity `Text` property in the dialog.

Based on your scenario, I create the following sample code, which work for me on Web Chat, you can refer to it.

*In MessagesController:*

```
else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
{
    // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
    // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
    // Not available in all channels

    IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = activity as IConversationUpdateActivity;
    if (iConversationUpdated != null)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        foreach (var member in iConversationUpdated.MembersAdded ?? System.Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
        {
            // if the bot is added, then   
            if (member.Id == iConversationUpdated.Recipient.Id)
            {
                var reply = ((Activity)iConversationUpdated).CreateReply("Hi, Welcome to Systenics.");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

                //set value to Text property
                activity.Text = "show choices";
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*In dialog:*

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}


public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;

    var mes = activity.Text?.ToString();

    if (mes == "show choices")
    {
        var descriptions = new string[] { "Request a Quote", "More Information About Jobs" };
        PromptDialog.Choice(
            context: context,
            resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
            options: descriptions,
            prompt: "Please select an option below:",
            retry: "Selected option not available.",
            promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
            );
    }
    else
    {
        if (mes == "More Information About Jobs")
        {
            var replymes = context.MakeMessage();
            replymes.Text = "Click on this link to know more about jobs [https//www.abc.com](https//www.abc.com)";

            await context.PostAsync(replymes);
        }
        else if (mes == "Request a Quote")
        {
            //your code logic here
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text}");
        }


        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: This SO thread: ["Start conversation with a PromptDialog in MS BotFramework"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669311/start-conversation-with-a-promptdialog-in-ms-botframework/51704547#51704547) discussed a similar scenario, please refer to it.